# Can't install latest Angular version

Tags: angular-cli

This is happening since there is some changes in `package.json` file which is not properly applied. When trying to run `npm -install @angular/cli` I encounter this problem

> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ent: https://openpgpj'

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that all your changes are checkedin if you are running it in your office machine.
now we would need to clear the cache by running this commmans in admin mode in powershell `npm cache clean --force`
after running this command try to again run the same command `npm install -g @angular/cli`